# Elements belonging to the same duration

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Given a vector of a sorted timestamps in microseconds, I need to determine the size of elements belonging to the same duration (say second).

My idea is to iterate over the vector until the last element belonging to the same duration, do this for each element and return the size of the biggest sub-vector.

Is there a smarter idea (with low time complexity) ?

Comment: Binary search may be better than linear search for sorted things.

Comment: Does the duration vary?

Comment: No it can be 10 second, 1 minute, etc it's fix

Comment: If it's a fixed duration or there is a limited number of fixed durations, consider maintaining a separate container of duration bins. Eg `std::unordered_map<durationstamp, int> bincounts;` As you add an item, `bincounts[timestamp/duration]--;` When you remove an item `bincounts[timestamp/duration]++;`, and when a time period falls out of of significance, you remove the bin so that the container doesn't keep growing.

Comment: @user4581301, thank you for your reply, could you please write an answer so I can accept it ? Thank you

Comment: Just to check, is this approach is most efficient than binary search ? Is not supporting sliding window ?

Comment: You can find in one pass, quantity is difference between 1st greater and 1st not less: `auto [nl,gt] = std::equal_range(begin(vec),end(vec),searched); return gt-nl;`

Comment: You take an extra small hit when adding and removing an item from the `vector` and waste a bit of space on the `unordered_map`, but getting the count of any one bin is O(1). Searching for the largest or smallest bin is still O(n), just potentially a much smaller n. I can't guarantee it's faster because there is overhead in maps. They generally don't play as nice with cache as a `vector` does.

Comment: Note that with `std::equal_range`, you're calling `std::equal_range` for every duration and get an O(bins) that calls an O(log(n)) function. O(bins*log(n)), which may or may not be better than the raw O(n), but is probably better than what I pitched.

Comment: If you can store the bin counts in a circular buffer instead of a map, the counting approach will really zoom. If we can figure out how to detect wrap around and re-zero a reused bin.

Comment: How does data arrive? Is it sequential chronologically? Is the timestamp of input n+1 guaranteed to be after the timestamp of input n?

Comment: Yes, it's sorted and if not I apply std::sort

Comment: Is the data in a big file or collection of files or does it come at the program in a more-or-less real-time feed?

Comment: It's feeded from different sources.

Comment: why is this tagged `linx`,`ubuntu` and `gcc`? For a `language-agnostic` question asking for an `algorithm` also the `c++` tag is offtopic

Comment: I code using c++. Other tags have been removed

Comment: The language doesn't matter, you're not asking about a C++ issue. Fixed the tags for you.

Answer (score 0):

I expect those posting comments are suggesting something like the following. This is Ruby code, but I readers who do not know Ruby can view it as pseudo code and should have no difficulty following it, particularly because I've displayed the results of intermediated calculations.

Suppose

```
arr = [1, 1, 3, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9]
```

A "current index" will always point to the first value in a group. In this example it will take on values `0` (the first `1`), `2` (the first `3`), `3`  (the first `5`), `5` (the first `6`), `9` (the first `8`) and `11` (the first `9`).

The method `bsearch_index` performs a binary search to return the index of the next higher value relative to a current index. If, for example, the current index is `3` (the first `5`), `bsearch_index` will return `5` (the first `6`). If there is no greater value than that at the current index (here when the current index is `11`, pointing at the first `9`), `bsearch_index` returns `nil` and there is an adjustment that can be seen in the code.

```
best = { :val=>nil, :len=>-Float::INFINITY }
curr_idx = 0
curr_val = arr[curr_idx]

arr.each do |x|
  puts
  puts "x = #{x}, curr_idx = #{curr_idx}, curr_val = #{curr_val}, best = #{best}"
  i = arr.bsearch_index { |x| x > curr_val }  
  i = arr.size if i.nil?
  puts "i from bsearch_idx = #{i}"

  diff = i - curr_idx
  puts "diff = #{diff}"

  if diff > best[:len]
    puts "best updated"
    best = { :val=>curr_val, :len=>diff }
  end

  break if i == arr.size
  curr_idx = i
  curr_val = arr[curr_idx]
end

puts
puts best
```

The following is displayed.

```
x = 1, curr_idx = 0, curr_val = 1, best = {:val=>nil, :len=>-Infinity}
i from bsearch_idx = 2
diff = 2
best updated

x = 1, curr_idx = 2, curr_val = 3, best = {:val=>1, :len=>2}
i from bsearch_idx = 3
diff = 1

x = 3, curr_idx = 3, curr_val = 5, best = {:val=>1, :len=>2}
i from bsearch_idx = 5
diff = 2

x = 5, curr_idx = 5, curr_val = 6, best = {:val=>1, :len=>2}
i from bsearch_idx = 9
diff = 4
best updated

x = 5, curr_idx = 9, curr_val = 8, best = {:val=>6, :len=>4}
i from bsearch_idx = 11
diff = 2

x = 6, curr_idx = 11, curr_val = 9, best = {:val=>6, :len=>4}
i from bsearch_idx = 14
diff = 3

{:val=>6, :len=>4}
```

The desired array, `[6, 6, 6, 6]` can be easily constructed from the final value of `best`.

A binary search works well when there are many instances of each value. On the other hand, if there are many different values and few instances of each it may be faster to simply enumerate the array, avoiding the overhead involved in performing a binary search.